# How can I resolve an ambigious type runtime error in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I have this haskell function which calculates the number in a given position of this infinite list:

```
[2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,...]
```

So for the n-th new number the list would be l(n-1) ++ [n] ++ l(n-1).
I have implemented this function:

```
getNumb theta = if ((floor (logBase 2 theta)) == ceiling (logBase 2 theta))
              then (floor (logBase 2 theta)) + 2
              else getNumb (2*(floor (logBase 2 theta)) - theta)
```

but when I run it like this: `getNumb 10` I get this error:

```
<interactive>:3:1: error:
* Could not deduce (RealFrac t0) arising from a use of `getNumb'
  from the context: Integral p
    bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral p => p
    at <interactive>:3:1-10
  The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the expression: getNumb 10
  In an equation for `it': it = getNumb 10

<interactive>:3:9: error:
* Could not deduce (Num t0) arising from the literal `10'
  from the context: Integral p
    bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral p => p
    at <interactive>:3:1-10
  The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
    instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    ...plus two others
    ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the first argument of `getNumb', namely `10'
  In the expression: getNumb 10
  In an equation for `it': it = getNumb 10
```

As far as I understand the problem lies in the return type of the function which is not compatible with the input type. Is this correct? If yes how do I fix it?

Note: This the output of `:t` and supposedly it is correct to return an `Integer`

```
*Main> :t getNumb
getNumb
  :: (RealFrac t, Floating t, Integral p, Integral t) => t -> p
```

Comment: This is *not* a runtime error, but a compile error. After the compilation step, the types are "gone".

Comment: The signature of getNumb gives away the answer. t should be both `Integral` and `Floating`. `Double` is an instance `Floating` not `Integral`. `Int` is an instance of `Integral` not  `Floating`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing logarithms is an inefficient way to find the value. Instead, work your way *down* the "tree", and compute the index on the way back up. This requires only an `Integral` constraint on the argument, since you never do anything except divide it by 2.

Note that all even indices evaluate to 2; the odd ones are computed recursively.

```
getNumb theta | even theta = 2
              | otherwise = 1 + getNumb (theta `quot` 2)
```

`even` is implemented in terms of `rem`, and both `quot` and `rem` are just wrappers around `quotRem`, so you might want to simply call `quotRem` yourself.

```
getNumb theta = case quotRem theta 2 of
                   (_, 0) -> 2
                   (q, _) -> 1 + getNum q
```

As proof that this works, note that you can map the function over the natural numbers to get back the original list:

```
> map getNumb [0..30]
[2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2]
```